# Highcharts returning error #15

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, highcharts, mapping

I'm getting the following error:[Highcharts error #15](https://www.highcharts.com/errors/15) I'm not quite sure I understand this error. I'm using Highcharts and making a $getJson() call to an API that returns data. The data returned looks like the following:

```
[ {
"timestamp" : 1503151200,
"price" : 4062.46,
"volume24h" : 123093.45
}, {
"timestamp" : 1503158400,
"price" : 3997.26,
"volume24h" : 120506.08
}, {
"timestamp" : 1503165600,
"price" : 4050.96,
"volume24h" : 114699.99
},
```

I have two functions that are looping and mapping the data. One for the 'timestamp' and 'price' and the other for the 'volume24'. The second function mapping the volume is causing error #15 and I'm not sure why. If I change the data coming from the API call then it won't be accurate. What am I doing wrong? Please see my complete code in the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/London804/dL5g5to4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one function to loop through the data. Once I removed volumeData, put it's loop inside of mappedData and passed mappedData to the second data object in series, highCharts rendered as expected. This surprised me because the [documentation](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume) example does it by passing two different objects.

```
series: [{
     type: 'area',
     name: `Bitcoin in USD`,
     data: mappedData,
     }, {
     type: 'column',
     data: mappedData,
     yAxis: 1,
}]
```